# Fastest and most scalable way of searching a combination of three MySQL textfields

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have three fields in a MySQL table - Brand, Range and Model and approx 8,000 models each with a brand and a range.

I am creating a jquery autocomplete search which uses a json response to return the 10 most likely matches to the users input. The json query will match the user input against the concatenation of Brand + Range + Model as soon as a minimum of 3 characters have been input.

The system will initially be used by a small group of people but could eventually be used by thousands as such I am trying to work out the most effective way of performing this search.

The three possible ways of doing this I have come up with are:

- create a new field in the models table which is updated daily with a cron job to create a single field with brand + ' ' + range + ' ' + model and search against this field
- include the concatenation in the MySQL query and search against this
- create a view with the concatenation and search against that

Which of these ways (or perhaps something different) would be the quickest and most scalable way of combining the three fields in order to be searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [MySQL Fulltext Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

Comment: Thanks, from the user notes I've seen this post:

Hyphen '-' characters break literals at the moment. 
A search for something like "GATA-D22S690" finds 
all entries containing GATA and not the full 
hyphenated text. The '-' character is treated as a 
word stop even within literals. The same is true if 
any of the special text search modifiers are used (eg 
+, -, ~) so that hyphenated literals are not correctly 
found with full text searches.

Most of the models have hyphens and this is the key part of the search, I notice the post is pretty old, do you know if this is still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to tackle this would be to provide select boxes containing each element.

Ajax would then fill in the range of Ranges when a Brand is chosen.

When a Range is picked the Models would be populated and so on ...

This avoid typos, eg "Madza".

If indeed the GUI and the use-case you describe governs your sql select, and you must allow a free-text field and you can and must make your users type "Mazda 6 spacewagon" then according to your 3 letter rule only entering "Maz" will fire off a select, that may as well be

```
SELECT brand, range, model where brand LIKE "$brand%";
```

The results will just be too scattergun.

Comment: Thanks but there's already a 3 dropdown sequential selector in the system - this an add-on the client has requested (and my boss has approved) the specification is a single text field that be typed in - so using your example of cars I can expect anthing from 'RX7' to 'Mercedes S-Class coupe'.

Comment: Then I'd take your first idea and create a string field you can search on - then based on your conversation with ThomasWienart above - remove hyphens as you do it (and other control chars if needed), and remove hyphens when the ajax search is fired off. You'd then expect typing RX7 to return just those records.